# If $T(t)$ is a semigroup, why is $t\mapsto T(t)x$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ be a semigroup on $E$
- $x\in E$ with $$\left\|T(h)x-x\right\|_E\xrightarrow{h\to0+}0\tag1$$ (i.e. $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous at $x$)

> In many books, we can find that $$\frac1h\int_t^{t+h}T(s)x\:{\rm d}s=T(t)x\tag2\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0,$$ but why does the Riemann integral on the left-hand side of $(2)$ exist at all?

By $(1)$, the only thing we shoulbe be able to conclude is that $$\operatorname{orb}x:[0,\infty)\to E\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto T(t)x$$ is **right**-continuous, but in order to show that $(2)$ holds, it seems like that we need that $\operatorname{orb}x$ is **continuous**. As far as I'm not mistaken, this cannot generally be shown.

> What am I missing?

**EDIT**: By $(1)$, we easily see that $\operatorname{orb}x$ is right-continuous, since if $t\ge0$, then $$\|(\operatorname{orb}x)(t+h)-(\operatorname{orb}x)(t)\|_E\le\|T(t)\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\|T(h)x-x\|_E\tag4$$ for all $h\ge0$.

But I don't think we can show left-continuity (without a local boundedness assumption). If $t\ge0$, then $$T(t)=T(t-h)T(h)\tag6$$ and hence $$\|(\operatorname{orb}x)(t-h)-(\operatorname{orb}x)(t)\|\le\|T(t-h)\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\|x-T(h)x\|_E\tag7$$ for all $h\in[0,t]$. Now I don't see how we can conclude, since there is generally no bound for $\|T(t-h)\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}$.

Comment: What do you mean by Riemann integral for  a Banach valued function? You should search the net for at Dunford/Pettis/Bochner intragals.

Comment: @geetha290krm There is no proble to define the Riemann integral for Banach space valued functions.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486785/how-do-we-need-to-apply-the-uniform-boundedness-principle-to-show-that-a-strongl answers this question?

Answer (score 0):

The continuity at $s=0$ implies the continuity on $[t,t+h]$ (by the semigroup property and the exponential bound). Hence, the Bochner integrability.

**Edit:**
For $t\ge h\ge 0$:
\begin{align*}
\|(\operatorname{orb}x)(t-h)-(\operatorname{orb}x)(t)\| &\le\|T(t-h)\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\|x-T(h)x\|_E \\
& \le M e^{\omega (t-h)} \|x-T(h)x\|_E \; \to 0 \text{ as } h \to 0^+.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think you are wrong. Please see my edit.

Comment: see the edited answer..

Comment: Don't you need strong continuity of the semigroup in order to prove the existence of $M$ and $\omega$? I'm pretty sure you do ... Actually, I think you do ...

Comment: Yes, we need it..

Comment: Well, then this is not useful, since a strongly continuous semigroup is always locally bounded :)